# Depth neural netwok for reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Are there any theoretical/experimental results showing the # of layers/# of nodes per layer for reinforcement learning (specifically for DDQN)? Or is it art/trial&error?

Answer (score 2):

This depends heavily on the task, but typically, the size of networks used in RL is significantly smaller than in other applications. 2 to 3 fully connected layers is typical for Atari and Mujoco environments. Somewhere from 16 to 256 neurons per layer is common.

Some exceptions I can think of are the large scale experiments run by OpenAI and Deepmind with Dota / Go / Starcraft, where they used pretty massive neural networks and a correspondingly ridiculous amount of compute power.

> Or is it art/trial&error?

It's definitely trial and error -- RL is famously finicky when it comes to hyperparameters. I recall seeing a paper where the authors specified the one of the layers had precisely 87 neurons, the next had precisely ?? neurons, and so on. Which just goes to how precisely things had to be tuned to get the system to work.

Comment: I wonder if there any guidances how neural network size scales with # of states. In my case task is for autopilot to glide from some position above the earth to the airport. I am still in 2D in vertical plane so the state is 4 dimensional (position/velocity in spherical). The only control action is angle of attack. There are lots of parameters to tune - learning rate, discount factor, extent of exploration and how it anneals during the learning, network architecture... I am bit lost. Episodes sometimes have to be stopped yearly because glider hits the ground.

Comment: yeah for such a small state, a relatively small network should do the trick.